# Describe $S=(-1,2) \cup [3, \infty)$ as open, closed, or neither, and find $S^o$, $(S^c)^o$, and $(S^o)^c$

Tags: real-analysis

> Describe $S=(-1,2) \cup [3, \infty)$ as open, closed, or neither, and find 
>   $S^o$, 
>   $(S^c)^o$, and
>   $(S^o)^c$

**(a) Open?**

the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the number $3$ is not contained in the set. $3$ is therefore not an interior point. As an open set is such that all points in the set are interior, $S$ is not open.

---

**(b) Closed?**

As $S$ does not contain all its boundary points such as $-1$ and $2$, it is not closed.

---

**(c)$S^o$?**

$S^o=(-1,2) \cup (3, \infty)$ as  the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the number $3$ is not contained in the set.

---

**(d)$(S^c)^o$?**

$(S^c)^o = \left[ (- \infty, -1] \cup [2,3) \right]^o=( -\infty, -1) \cup (2,3)$

---

**(e)$(S^o)^c$?**

$(S^o)^c = \left[      (-1,2) \cup (3, \infty) \right]^c= (- \infty, -1] \cup [2,3]$

---

Am i going in the right direction? Is there a more efficient way to explain?

Specific to b: is the definition of closed set is to have contained the boundary points or limit points?

Much appreciated

Comment: Your solutions look fine.  There are multiple definitions of a closed set, but one of them is a set which contains all of its boundary points.